# SMARTY, submit FORM with only changed fields. Ignore all fields contain default value

Tags: php, html, forms, smarty

Two arrays are passed to tpl file, first gets all row elements, second one is used for avaliable options. Then i'm populating a form with those data.

Till now it's easy.
So we have:

```
field1 | field2 | field3 
------------
1  | some_desc | select val1, val2,val3...<br>
1  | some_desc | select val1, val2,val3...<br>
1  | some_desc | select val1, val2,val3...<br>
```

the default value for all form is `val1`

when I change `field3` from `val1` to `val2` or `val3` and submit data,
**I would like to pass only those elements of form where change happends.** Is it possible in SMARTY, without javascript?

I know I can submit all, and in PHP ignore those POSTed with default val1, but maybe SMARTY is so great, that there is solution for that.

Comment: Smarty only works server side and it's only function is render templates. So the answer is No. You will need javascript.

Comment: Hello,
I have edited a little your code and added your variables in backquotes for better overall look. :)